# Migrating from Tomcat 7 to 8 in Eclipse WTP: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8, eclipse-wtp

Everything worked fine in Eclipse with **Tomcat 7** + Java 8.

JSTL is in place:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Taglib is used in JSP:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

web.xml is standard 3.0.

Using Eclipse WST, module auto reloading off, serve modules without publishing on.

Now the only thing changed - migrated to **Tomcat 8**, and getting this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp (line: 1, column: 1)
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml
or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Is there any problem with running Tomcat8 in Eclipse?

Updating web.xml to 3.1 does not help.

**==EDIT==**

When running Tomcat 8 standalone (outside Eclipse), it also works fine.

Comment: Check the URL in the JSTL JARs - it must have changed between versions.  Your pages don't match anymore.

Comment: The URL of JSTL 1.2 did not change. The JSTL JAR itself is the same.

Comment: @duffymo why is this comment frequently the only one I run across from you?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You need to get out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the "*Serve modules without publishing*" feature.

Turning it off solved the issue.

[image]